# Why does one set of G9 led bulbs work and others do not?

Tags: electrical, led

I have 2 x identical ceiling lights (each with 5 bulbs) and recently decided to change the G9 led bulbs from bright white to cool white however only 1 of the lights worked. All 5 bulbs failed to light up in one but not the other. I changed back to the old bulbs - all lit up. I swapped the new bulbs from the lamp that was working but still nothing.
Both lamps are non dimmable and the switches are simple on/off type.
I am completely baffled as I can see no reason for this - can anyone suggest why this might be?
Yes, I have tried swapping all bulbs around but the Integral LED G9 bulb refuses to work in the one light fitting. It is a complete mystery- totally baffled.

Comment: If you're using a dimmer it could be that one set is dimmerable and the other not

Comment: No, these are not on a dimmer switch

Comment: what type of a switch do you have? ... please update the info in the question, not in comments

Comment: Just to be sure, do the bulbs from the non-working lamp work in the other one? Do mix-and-match sets of "working" and "non-working" bulbs work in either? Do mixed sets of new & old temperature bulbs work in either?

Comment: Yes, I have tried swapping all bulbs around but the Integral LED G9 bulb refuses to work in the one light fitting. It is a complete mystery- totally baffled.

Comment: Maybe the bases are different lengths and the new set isn't making contact?  ... https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207197/certain-light-bulbs-not-working-in-fixture